# Is there a synset for phrasal verbs?

Tags: nlp, nltk, embeddings

Is there a database of phrasal verbs of similar semantics? Eg. one where querying ‘get in touch’ would return ‘get in contact with’, among other phrasal verbs of similar meanings?

If not, given a phrasal verb how would you obtain others of similar meanings?

Comment: maybe you can approach it as a paraphrasing problem?

Comment: Well I would like to use this as an intermediate step to solve something like paraphrasing

Comment: was the dataset provided of any use to you?

Answer (score 1):

## Dataset

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/phrasalverbsenglish) is a data set I created.

There are $143$ phrasal verbs. However, since some have multiple meanings, there are $181$ phrasal verbs pairs.

## Examples

```
phrasal_verb | meaning
------------------------
black out    | faint
calm down    | become more relaxed
get off      | leave
get off      | remove
hold on      | wait
hold on      | grip tightly
```

## Creation

I couldn't find any ready made, but I created the dataset by scraping [this website](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/list-of-phrasal-verbs/).

I loaded the data set and for '*phrasal verb*' I found the meaning in the '*Meaning*' column by applying the following rules:

```
def tokenize_meaning(sentence: str) -> list:
    """
    Splits the string in the meaning column into a list of possible phrasal verbs.
    :param sentence: str from the meaning column
    :return: list of strings
    """
    meanings = re.split('\d\.\s+', sentence)
    meanings = flatten([re.split(', ', meaning) for meaning in meanings])
    meanings = [meaning for meaning in meanings if meaning[:3] == 'To ']
    meanings = flatten([re.split(' or ', meaning) for meaning in meanings])
    meanings = [meaning for meaning in meanings if not meaning == '']
    meanings = [re.sub('[\(|\/].*', '', meaning) for meaning in meanings]
    meanings = [re.sub('[.,?!]', '', meaning) for meaning in meanings]
    meanings = [re.sub('To ', '', meaning) for meaning in meanings]
    meanings = [meaning.strip() for meaning in meanings]

    return meanings
```